# XSLT - Group foreach values inside new parent

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, dspace

I'm learning XSLT 1.0 and I have a little problem of logic and knowledge too. I am working with dspace 6, and I want to change the output for some xslt lines code.

When I retrieve some metadata with:

```
<xsl:for-each select="doc:metadata/doc:element[@name='dc']/doc:element[@name='date']/doc:element[@name='dateType']/doc:element/doc:field[@name='value']">    
    <creator><xsl:value-of select="." /></creator>    
</xsl:for-each>
```

I get:

```
<creator>Pavel Hitch</creator>
<creator>Adan Riviera</creator>
```

What I want to do is that looks like this:

```
<creators>
    <creator>Pavel Hitch</creator>
    <creator>Adan Riviera</creator>
</creators>
```

Edit: My problem is when I get just one value, put the "creator tag" only, but with two o more values returned, add the "creators" parent.

I tried save the "foreach" output into a variable, use position() and last() to make some conditionals but the "creators" tag just repet itself (thanks to te foreach), trying this give me some close tag error:

```
xsl:for-each select="doc:metadata/doc:element[@name='dc']/doc:element[@name='date']/doc:element[@name='dateType']/doc:element/doc:field[@name='value']">
<xsl:variable name="lastPos" select="last()"/>
<xsl:variable name="initPos" select="position()"/>      

<xsl:if test="$lastPos>'1' and $initPos='1' ">
    <Creators>
</xsl:if>
    <creator><xsl:value-of select="." /></creator>
<xsl:if test="$lastPos = $initPos">
    </Creators>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I hope you can help me, I'm really newbie.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `<creators>` tag/element belongs *outside* of the `for-each` loop to surround it when there is more than one element.

> when I get just one value, put the "creator tag" only, but with two o more values returned, add the "creators" parent.

So this can be solved using an `xsl:choose` which counts the elements to differ between these two cases:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="count(doc:metadata/doc:element[@name='dc']/doc:element[@name='date']/doc:element[@name='dateType']/doc:element/doc:field[@name='value']) > 1">
    <creators>
      <xsl:for-each select="doc:metadata/doc:element[@name='dc']/doc:element[@name='date']/doc:element[@name='dateType']/doc:element/doc:field[@name='value']">    
        <creator><xsl:value-of select="." /></creator>    
      </xsl:for-each>
    </creators>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:for-each select="doc:metadata/doc:element[@name='dc']/doc:element[@name='date']/doc:element[@name='dateType']/doc:element/doc:field[@name='value']">    
      <creator><xsl:value-of select="." /></creator>    
    </xsl:for-each>      
  </xsl:otherwise>      
</xsl:choose>
```

The `xsl:for-each` in the second case may be superfluous, but it takes care of the (theoretical) possibility that there are no creators.

Comment: You are right! I edit my question because the creators node depends If I get two o more values on the foreach, :)

Comment: thank you very much, with the choose and count functions, I can finish this. ;)